# An electron in time

Tags: quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

I've read many times now that when one measures the spin of an entangled electron (for example) the state of its partner is known instantaneously and this is true across any theoretical distance.

Surprisingly enough I haven't yet read anyone to refute this as a basic fact although I've read a million opinions that try to explain it. I don't have a personal opinion.

I was thinking though that John Wheeler once phoned Richard Feynman and perhaps jokingly said all electrons were the same electron. Feynman was known to tell another professor once that the basis of physics was that two things cannot be in the same place at the same time.

It's a bit (a lot) of a wild card but since this measurement of entangled electrons seems to fix the spins at the same instant the information would be travelling faster than light (in a vacuum).

If the speed of light was exceeded then this would allow an electron to be in two places (with same or evolved spin position). We would be looking at the same electron in two different times.

What did Wheeler mean by saying there is only one electron since entanglement requires two?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe). But essentially, the idea is that the electron exists as a continuous thread-like object embedded in the 4D *spacetime*, all tangled up, and that what we perceive as individual electron particles (entangled or not) are the places where a 3D "time-slice" intersects that global object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment of @FilipMilovanović has basically answered the question, but I’d like to clarify that the essential ingredient to Wheeler’s suggestion is propagation backwards in time. The quantum world has a lot of strange behaviors, including entanglement and others which might suggest faster-than-light (FTL) motion (or at least FTL information propagation). One way to get around this, since FTL propagation is manifestly incompatible with special relativity, would be to allow for backwards time propagation instead. The time symmetry in the laws of physics and possibility to resolve paradoxes with “advanced” solutions to the equations (i.e. ones with backward time evolution) is the idea that Wheeler and Feynman were exploring in the 40’s with their absorber theory, for example.

If you think about this for a minute, you’ll see that allowing for propagation both forward and backwards in time would easily allow one particle to be in multiple places at the same time, or for information to be “teleported” instantly across space-like intervals, all while all while maintaining that information and particles travel at the speed of light or slower.

Sure, everything propagates at the speed of light or slower. But which way through time do they propagate? It’s a huge loophole around our intuition!

Comment: Would the particle not have to divide itself to be in multiple places?