# Black Hole Escape By Quantum Tunneling

Tags: black-holes, wavelength, quantum-tunneling

The first minute of this explanation: https://youtu.be/ZgOhQhpoczs about Black Hole evaporation (Hawking Radiation) talks about particles with de Broglie wavelengths bigger than the Event Horizon.

*Thus* particles **inside** the EH can get out by Quantum Tunneling. To this I have two questions:

1) What types of events would create particles with such wavelengths (and would this even count for SMBH's millions of miles across)?

2) Would the particles in the singularity be excluded from this process or do parts of the singularity (in real Black Holes) get to tunnel out too?

Comment: Time inside a black hole (assuming the Schwarzschild interior) moves from the horizon to the "center", so tunneling out means "tunneling" back in time. Can a particle "tunnel out" from today to yesterday? This is not what quantum tunneling is.

Comment: The physical meaning of the horizon is that everything beyond it is in the future and so cannot affect us in any way, because it does not exist yet.

Comment: @safesphere - I am too confused to say anything but thanks right now

Comment: Space and time are relative. Normally space goes from point A to point B and time goes from this moment to the next. Black holes twist spacetime to such an extreme that this picture may be reversed when one sees it from afar like us. Simplest black holes are called Schwarzschild. They don’t exist, still everyone talks about them. In them we see that time inside goes from the horizon to the “center”. So escaping is not an option, as nothing can move back in time. In real black holes that actually exist things are different and there is no unified opinion yet most agree there still is no escape.

Comment: @safesphere - have you seen this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/532732/246973 - if a particle would propagate backward in time what would still prevent it from leaving black hole. Could we regard time as a "barrier" in this case?

Comment: When a particle moves backward in time, we see it as an antiparticle moving forward in time. We see this antiparticle falling into a BH and unable to come back, because it is moving forward in time. Now, if this particle “thinks of itself” as a particle moving back in time, then it sees the BH as reversed in time. A BH reverses in time is a White Hole. The WH horizon us called “anti-horizon”, cause it is reversed. Things can come out, but cannot fall in. So this particle sees itself flying out from inside a WH while we see it as an antiparticle falling in. Like running the same film backward.

Comment: @safesphere - Aha! --- and never leaves "anti-horizon" because it only existed in the past... food for thoughts. Have a great day or "anti-day" depending on how you see yourself : )